# What physical properties of silver would contribute to the sound of a musical instrument?

Tags: acoustics, material-science

A question was recently asked on Musical Practice & Performance, asking what physical properties of silver would contribute to the sound of percussion instruments. It is likely to be off-topic there; I wondered if any of you physicists/material scientists would be able to offer a humble musician information on this site.

It would also be interesting to know what contribution solid-silver or silver-plated components would make to brass/woodwind instruments, and what properties of silver are responsible for this.

Comment: Materials have different properties such as density, rigidity and so on, and these affect the objects natural frequencies. Can you link the question?

Comment: I can, but I think one of the problems with the question was that it wasn't asked particularly well either…! It is on hold to be closed.  Here it is: http://music.stackexchange.com/q/16515/9198

Comment: Do you think you can be a bit more specific about what you mean by "sound"? As in what aspects of the sound are of interest here. Reading the linked question, I guess something like "purity of tone" (which is something we could discuss with physics) might be of interest. Or maybe how long a ring lasts once bell is struck (something about damping of oscillations in the instrument). What aspects of the sound are you interested in having explained by a "good" answer to this question?

Comment: Well, yes, I know the usual SE question format should ask a clearly defined question to get a clearly defined answer!  But, in this case, I confess I wanted to see the reaction on your site, in order to assess how to pursue this topic. Already, I think you suggest two good specific questions. I think the "purity of tone" aspect is possibly more interesting, and closely related to the original question. I'd be happy to hear a suggested way to frame this question, to be most suitable for this site...